# Combination of header - main_wrapper makes page scrollabe for header-height

Tags: css, xhtml, sticky-footer

I'm making a webpage with a fixed footer. If there is a lot of content, there must be a scroll bar. If there is only one line of input in the content-part, there is no need to scroll. The way the page is made now, gives me a scroll bar all the time! It scrolls just as far so that the header disappears from the screen. --> My header is 150px high and I can scroll exactly 150px. But I don't want this. What is wrong with my html or CSS?

This is the html:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1>The <span>ultimate</span><br />DVD collection</h1>
</div>
<div id="main_wrapper">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="choose">#abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</div>
        <div id="content">Main content comes here.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p>My Name <span>admin log-in</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    /*position: relative;*/
}
#header {
    height: 150px;
    background: linear-gradient(left, #2a2620, #a35e47);
    border-top: 10px solid #f6e6c5;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #f6e6c5;
    background-color: #a35e47;
}
h1 {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 35px auto 0;
    font-family:'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #a35e47;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #f6e6c5, 4px 4px 8px #000000;
}
h1 span {
    font-family:'Aclonica', Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.75em;
}
#main_wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-jPxP0Hgum7o/T0OiL_IupqI/AAAAAAAAAMs/Xu5zNtqULoE/s1600/IMG_0665+Hollywood+star.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 60%;
    background-color: #5a646d;
}
#main {
    width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: .75;
    /*overflow: auto;*/
}
#choose {
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-family: georgia, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 2em;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
#footer {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 10px solid #f6e6c5;
    background: linear-gradient(left, #2a2620, #a35e47);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

You can also see my code in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kru5f/).

What am I doing wrong? (look at the scroll bar in [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9CRs.jpg))
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around it using this explanation: http://dorayme.netweaver.com.au/ciaran.html

My wrapper now has a position:absolute with top: and bottom: equal to the height of header and footer (+ height of borders)

```
#main_wrapper{
position: absolute;
top: 170px; /* header + bordertop + borderbottom */
bottom: 50px; /* footer + bordertop */
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-image: url('path/to/img.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 40%;
background-color: #5a646d;
}
```

Thx to Johan Sundén for pushing me into the right direction!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove height:100% on the main-wrapper. The height of 100% means 100% of the available space inside the parent (the header and the main-wrapper has the same parent). But the main-wrapper is not aware of the headers height. So the result will be 100% + 150px.

Comment: OK, I understand. But when I remove the height for the main_wrapper, this causes that the background for my content stops and leaves a white block until the footer.

Comment: I added a picture in my first post. When I remove height for main_wrapper everything disappears after my <div id="content"></div> tags and only the footer at the bottom of the page remains.

Comment: Cant you just put the background image style on the body tag instead?

Comment: No, that doesn't do it, either. It gets my main_content to stop after the last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few adjustment in style.
I have given percentage height for your container(you can adjust them as per you need) and scroll property to div.

```
    <style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    body {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #666;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        /*position: relative;*/
    }
    #header {
        height: 15%px;
        background: linear-gradient(left, #2a2620, #a35e47);
        border-top: 10px solid #f6e6c5;
        border-bottom: 10px solid #f6e6c5;
        background-color: #a35e47;
    }
    h1 {
        width: 960px;
        margin: 35px auto 0;
        font-family:'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
        font-size: 3.5em;
        line-height: 1em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #a35e47;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #f6e6c5, 4px 4px 8px #000000;
    }
    h1 span {
        font-family:'Aclonica', Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.75em;
    }
    #main_wrapper {
        /*height: 100%;*/
        /*min-height: 100%;*/
        background-image: url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-jPxP0Hgum7o/T0OiL_IupqI/AAAAAAAAAMs/Xu5zNtqULoE/s1600/IMG_0665+Hollywood+star.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 50% 60%;
        background-color: #5a646d;
    }
    #main {
        width: 960px;
        height: 70%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: #fff;
        opacity: .75;
        /*overflow: auto;*/
        overflow:scroll;
    }
    #choose {
        margin-left: 20px;
        font-family: georgia, serif;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        line-height: 2em;
        letter-spacing: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #content {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
    #footer {
        height: 15%;
        width: 100%;
        border-top: 10px solid #f6e6c5;
        background: linear-gradient(left, #2a2620, #a35e47);
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Hi Saurav, thx for the input, but that doesn't do the trick. The header HAS to be 150px. And I don't want a scrollbar (unless the amount of text is too long to be shown). Now I have very little text (1 sentence) so it should not be possible to scroll. The way I made my css/html now, I can scroll down for 150px. This should not happen.

Comment: @user2231930 It seems that you want something like following irrespective of screen size.
1>Header should be 150px
2>Header & footer should always visible.
3>Only the middle container will have scroll on the basis on content
Please inform me if I am in right track or not.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you want to say. (irrespective??)

Comment: @Jootje just confirming that I have understood the question properly.